# How to write keys and key sequences?

Tags: support, site-usage

Hi, I've seen people writing keys and key sequences for things like `Ctrl + C`, where the text looks like a key on a keyboard.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think he's asking about how to do keyboard formatting on SF, which can be done with the kbd tag.  For example:

`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>`

Should render as:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>

Well, I see it doesn't work here on meta.SF, which might be a glitch.  [This question on meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26207/how-can-i-format-as-keyboard-keys) refers to the kbd tag being disabled on meta (I think people were drawing pictures of castles with it), so maybe it's disabled on all the meta sites.